# Using 'for' as a coordinating conjunction at the beginning of a sentence – is this acceptable?

Tags: word-order, conjunctions, coordinating-conjunctions

As I understand it, 'for' is a coordinating conjunction. Learning German as a second language has taught me specifics about reforming sentences, but it is an awful lot less common in English. If I were to rearrange the sentence: "I ate lunch, for I was hungry," so that 'for' was the first word of the sentence, by my reckoning I should end up with "For that I was hungry, I ate lunch." Does this new sentence have any grammatical errors? I inserted the word 'that' after 'for', because without it the sentence didn't sound right. Should I have? Is there a rule for that? Thank you in advance, an aspiring author.

**Additional Information:**
 I am not having problems with the sentence, this is a general question to increase my knowledge of the manipulations of coordinating conjuntions.

Comment: Re-arranging using for does not sound grammatical in my ears. A stilted example could be "To still my hunger, I ate lunch"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that *for* is a *coordinating conjunction*, the first of the so-called [FANBOYS](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/conjunctions.htm). But you cannot move a coordinated clause (starting with a FANBOY) to the front of a sentence:

> I was hungry, so I ate.
>
> *So I ate, I was hungry.

It is the same in German:

> Ich habe gegessen, denn ich hatte Hunger.
>
> *Denn ich Hunger hatte, habe ich gegessen.

However, you can move a clause with a *subordinating conjunction* to the front:

> *Because* I was hungry, I ate.
>
> *Da* ich Hunger hatte, habe ich gegessen.

Comment: I question the claim that _for_ Is a coordinator. It means _because_, which is undeniably a subordinator. In the ‘Cambridge Grammar of English’ (which is not the CGEL), Carter and McCarthy include _for_ in a list of subordinators and write explicitly in another part of the book that it is a subordinating conjunction.

Comment: @Barrie, Yes, the _Cambridge Grammar_ is correct in noting that, like other subordinating conjunctions, _for_ indicates "_a dependent relationship between the clauses [it introduces] and the main clause_" (p488). But it behaves differently from the others the CG lists in that cannot be fronted, which I think is the OP's main concern. As an aside, using _for_ to mean _because_ feels rather old-fashioned to me, and much more likely to be encountered in stories than everyday spoken English.

Comment: It is, and for that reason OP needs to be careful about using it.

Comment: @Shoe, can you tell me of some good references to learn more about the distinction between subordinating and coordinating conjunctions and the clauses they are respectively said to subordinate and coordinate?

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/598864/2085).

Answer (score 2):

*For*, as a coordinating conjunction, is rarely used to begin a sentence, *for* its function is to introduce the reason for the preceding clause. Putting the reason before the preceding clause makes it awkward, unless you use one of its substitutes - *because*, or use and after the comma.

> For I was hungry, I ate lunch.
>   For I was hungry, and I ate lunch. (doesn't stand alone well, and sounds antiquated)
>   Because I was hungry, I ate lunch.

There are, however, well known sentences beginning with that (in essence) 'coordinating conjunction':

> For I was hungry and you gave me something to eat, I was thirsty and...
>   For all have sinned, and come short of the glory of God...

For is more common as a preposition, and much easier to use as a sentence starter:

> For most of Haiti's citizens, living conditions are very bad.

Comment: Yes; one can consider structures like 'For all have sinned, and come short of the glory of God ...' to be sentence fragments. If clear in meaning and not overdone, quite acceptable.

Comment: +1 The classic example of _for_ as a coordinating conjunction gone wild occurs in the portion of Christopher Smart's long poem _Jubilate Agno_ commonly known as "[My Cat Jeoffry](http://www.creekcats.com/pnprice/Jeoffry.html)," in which 74 consecutive lines (and sentences) start with the word _for_ acting as a coordinating conjunction.