# Why do some sentences begin with for?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

lyrics from raekwon's north star from ob4cl:

No man, can judge for another
But each man must weigh all facts and circumstances
And find truth in his own judgment of righteousness
See, the way to evil, balance equality in no man
For no man is good and bad at the same time
Either you good, or you bad

Why does "For no man is good and bad at the same time" start with "for" and how does that change context/meaning?

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/289896/for-with-the-meaning-of-because It isn't necessarily the beginning of a sentence, just of a line of poetry.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using 'for' as a coordinating conjunction at the beginning of a sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/144100/using-for-as-a-coordinating-conjunction-at-sentence-beginning)

Comment: If the sentence (yes, I'll call it that) 'For no man is both good and bad at the same time.' were seen in formal prose, few nowadays would even bother to think about whether its grammaticality should be challenged. But there must of course be a valid semantic / logical link with the preceding text ('for' introducing a reason / explanation of the foregoing). Those aberrant but indisposable customers sometimes grouped as _FANBOYS_ (commonly accompanied by terrible syntactical analysis) are no longer considered inherently  improper words with which to start sentences.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth so, to change the structure of the sentence yet keep the meaning as is, how would that be said? or in other words, what does that sentence i used above mean? i just still can't get what there's said. can you change this sentence so that i can get its meaning - See, the way to evil, balance equality in no man For no man is good and bad at the same time Either you good, or you bad?
does it mean
a) since no man is good and bad at the same time, the way to evil balance equality in no man
or
b) since no man is good and bad at the same time, you are either good or bad
?

Comment: Lyrics are usually off-topic because they so often break the rules of grammar, and so often push definitions (who decides who is 'evil'? Top judges make mistakes, and sentences are very varied ... it doesn't seem a well-defined concept or well-regulated judging process).  I honestly don't know how 'See, the way to evil' is intended to be taken. The 'For' is easy, though: it means 'because'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth whether or not context makes full sense isn't my point. i'm asking whether "for" connects "see the way to evil, balance equality in no man" to "no man is good and bad at the same time" or " no man is good and bad at the same time" to" you are either good or bad". or in other words does it say  "the way to evil balance equality in no man, hence no man is good and bad at the same time" or does it say "no man is good and bad at the same time, hence you are either good or bad?

Comment: 'For/Because the facts of the matter are: no man is good and bad at the same time – either you're good, or you're bad.'

Comment: got it. thanks a lot